# Extent Report with Cucumber generate name with date format

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, extentreports

I use Extent Report with Cucumber and I can generate test reports as well. But I want to generate test report's name with date format like report-27-01-23.
I can change basefolder name in extent.properties but I can not change file name.
How can I do that in my properties file? Here is my properties file.

```
extent.reporter.spark.start=true
basefolder.name=test-output/reports
basefolder.datetimepattern=d-MMM-YY HH-mm-ss
extent.reporter.html.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.spark.out=d-MMM-YY HH-mm-ss.html
screenshot.dir=test-output/screenshots/
screenshot.rel.path=../screenshots/
extent.reporter.spark.vieworder=dashboard,test,exception,author,device,log
```

Comment: Can you post the content of 'extent-config.xml' file?

Comment: If you want to generate user defined extent report, _extent.reporter.spark.out_ property needs to be updated accordingly. In your case it should be changed to **report-dd-MM-YY.html**

Comment: @SrinivasuKaki it generated exactly like report-dd-MM-YY.html. It did not take the date to the filename.

Comment: @AbiSaran it's the basic extent-config.xml file. I did not change something.

Comment: @yunixos this is not possible. the file name is treated as a string literal and no parsing logic is present.